# Git - how to properly revert changes?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, git-flow

We just recently switched to git (using the gitflow branching model) and are having some trouble when we need to back out changes.

Unfortunately, we fairly often decide that a feature won't be going in a release due to issues found during regression or anytime fairly late in the test cycle. We can easily revert the merge commit for the feature branch to be backed out, but feature branches cut after the bad change was merged in will also contain that change and can bring it back to develop or a release branch before it should be released.

Example:

```
                               |reverts f1 
 develop-> X---o---o---Y---Z---R---P <- merge f2 to develop picks up f1
            \         /     \     /
        f1-> A---B---C  f2-> D---E
```

From the example, f1 is cut, worked on, and merged back to develop. f2 is cut and work begins. f1 is reverted from develop at commit R. f2 is then completed and merged back to develop at commit P. Commit P is where the problem is: f1 comes back into develop via this commit. Now, is there something we're doing wrong with the reverts? Is there any way to make sure reverted commits do not make their way back into develop? We revert by using 'revert -m1 '.

Is there anything we're doing wrong when we're reverting our merge commits? Is there any way we can make it so the commits from f1 that f2 picked up will not be included on the merge back to develop? Do we have to manually revert those commits on all forward feature branches? Should we instead be having dev cut all feature branches from Master, so we know they cannot be picking up any changes from features which may be reverted?

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your workflow except that you have to account for reverting of a commit as it applies to all children not just the develop branch. Because the feature branch f2 also has the changes for f1 i.e. f2 = f2 +f1 in your example and when you merge f2 back in git thinks you want f1 back in as well.

In your example above, you could include a commit R' on the f2 branch to accomplish what you would like to happen.

```
                               |reverts f1 
 develop-> X---o---o---Y---Z----R----P <- merge f2 to develop picks up f1
            \         /     \       /
        f1-> A---B---C  f2-> D--R'--E
                              **|reverts f1**
```

This is assuming that f2 is a long running branch. If it's not and you anticipate it to be a short branch then i'd hold off on the revert R and do it after you merge f2 and its sisters back into develop. This may be useful if you have quite a features being worked on in parallel.

```
                                     **|reverts f1** 
 develop-> X---o---o---Y---Z-------P---R-- <
            \         /     \     /
        f1-> A---B---C  f2-> D---E
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, so there's nothing we can really do outside of reverting the commits on feature branches that would have picked up f1. I'll have to script something to identify those branches, do the revert of those commits or, cherry pick the R' commit from trunk.